# sort the product by product price from low to high and vice versa in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, sorting, filter

I am creating a sort function for the product. but I have some problems with the render on the product page.

At first, when the product sort function is not implemented, the product list is still displayed as before. When the sort function is implemented, the product will list from low to high, and vice versa

This is my group component, which the place contain sort and filter function

```
const GroupBar = ({ handleSelectCategory, handleSelectPriceOption }) => {
  return (
    <Row className="group-bar">
      <Group
        title="Product group"
        element={
          <Dropdown
            items={["Milk Tea", "Juice"]}
            onSelect={handleSelectCategory}
          />
        }
      />
      <Group
        title="Sort by price"
        element={<Dropdown
          items={["Low to hight", "Hight to low"]}
          onSelect={handleSelectPriceOption}
        />}
      />
      <Group
        title="Search"
        element={<Search searchTerm="" />}
      />
    </Row>
  );
}

export default GroupBar;
```

This is the main page which contains the product list and also sorts and filter function, and also this is the place connect function sort and product .

```
const Product = () => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [priceOption, setpriceOption] = useState("");
  const handleSelectCategory = (item) => {
    setCategory(item);
  };

  const handleSelectPriceOption = (item) => {
    setpriceOption(item);
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-0">
      <Carousel />
      <Container>
        <GroupBar
          handleSelectCategory={handleSelectCategory}
          handleSelectPriceOption={handleSelectPriceOption}
        />
        <ProductContainer
          category={category}
          priceOption={priceOption}
        />
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

And here is `productlist`page, I pass param for that is `priceOption`. And useEffect for that.

```
const ProductList = ({
  products,
  category,
  priceOption,
  loading,
  fetchProductRequest,
  filterProducts,
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductRequest();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState("");
  const [sortProducts, setsortProducts] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = products
      .filter((it) => !category || it.category === category);
    setFilteredProducts(result);
  }, [category, products]);



     useEffect(() => {
     if (priceOption === "Low to hight") {
       const lth = products.sort((a, b) => a - b);
       setsortProducts(lth);
     }
     if (priceOption === "Hight to low") {
       const htl = products.sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse();
       setsortProducts(htl);
     }
   }, [priceOption, products, sortProducts])

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Loading />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {!!filteredProducts && filteredProducts.length > 0 ? (
          filteredProducts.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <ProductItem
                key={index}
                image={product.image}
                name={product.name}
                price={product.price}
              />
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <h4 className="center-title">Product list is empty!</h4>
          )}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

How can I combine both sort and filter functions into the same `useEffect`, and `return it in short instead of creating two different useEffect for each function?`

My sort function it does not work for me, It remains as intact as it was

And also in the `render` `what should I do for both functions to show the UI implemented on the product page`

Answer (score 0):

You should always sort the filtered products and not the original products. Inside the common function for sorting and filtering, just check if you have to filter something and perform all the filtering first followed by sorting. I'm assuming the `products` array contains all your original products. I'm also assuming that your logic for filtering and sorting is correct.

```
  //always use this state to show contents on the DOM
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(products);

  const sortAndFilter=()=>{
    //always filter and sort from the original array
    const results=products;
    //perform filtering first and then sorting on the filtered array
    if(category) 
    results = products.filter((it) => !category || it.category === category);
    if(priceOption)
    results = results.sort((it) => !priceOption || it.priceOption ==priceOption);

  setFilteredProducts(results);
  }
  useEffect(() => {

   if(category || priceOption) //check if you need to perform filtering/sorting
    sortAndFilter(); 
  else
   setFilteredProducts(products);
  }, [category, priceOption]);
```

Your render method seems alright to me and this should show the updated UI on the page.

Comment: I already update my question, could you please check it again, in Product page

Comment: Thank you so much, but as your comment, it does not work for me

Comment: Sort is by price ascending and descending